# RegEx in Kendo UI - TimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, kendo-ui, timepicker

could some one tell me how to add RegEx validation/ pattern for timepicker for KendoUI.

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Les7ccwk/3/)

I've tried  **`(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)`** pattern assigned directly in input field. doesn't work as expected.

what i need is, the timepicker should never allow user to enter alphabetic character except AM or PM and  special characters except **:** colan

but in that fiddle it will user enter alphabetic.also it get cleared when choose time from time picker.

if my explanation is not understandable, kindly see my fiddle.
still working on it with Jquery as well. but failed.

tried below code but make AM/PM disappear

```
function replaceBadInputs(val){
              val = val.replace(/[^\dh:]/, "");
              val = val.replace(/^[^0-2]/, "");
              val = val.replace(/^([2-9])[4-9]/, "$1");
              val = val.replace(/^\d[:h]/, "");
              val = val.replace(/^([01][0-9])[^:h]/, "$1");
              val = val.replace(/^(2[0-3])[^:h]/, "$1");      
              val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}[:h])[^0-5]/, "$1");
              val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}h)./, "$1");      
              val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}:[0-5])[^0-9]/, "$1");
              val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}:\d[0-9])./, "$1");
              return val;
        }
        // Apply input rules as the user types or pastes input
            $('.houronly').keyup(function(){
              var val = this.value;
              var lastLength;
              do {
                // Loop over the input to apply rules repeately to pasted inputs
                lastLength = val.length;
                val = replaceBadInputs(val);
              } while(val.length > 0 && lastLength !== val.length);
              this.value = val;
            });

            // Check the final result when the input has lost focus
            $('.houronly').blur(function(){
              var val = this.value;
              val = (/^(([PM][AM][01][0-9]|2[0-3])h)|(([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$/.test(val) ? val : "");
              this.value = val;
            });
```

hope someone help me and ll help others too in future

thanks in advance

Comment: Would you please credit the source you have copied that code from? That's the very least when you are using code you did not write yourself.

Comment: What isn't working the jsFiddle? (besides it accepting `29:00 AM`)

Comment: its belong from official telerik

Comment: Then link to the source, please.

Comment: @Halcyon there you delete time and type some character and the choose time from that. those characters will disappear as expected but i dont want enter like that .. keyCode validation will make input box disable under some scenarios

Comment: @Tomalak it has some unwanted piece of codes that's why put required codes